yt-dlp : You are using an unsupported version of Python. Only Python versions 3.9 and above are supported by yt-dlp
When using yt-dlp on ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8 or lower installed you may come across the following error when trying to use yt-dlp:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/bin/yt-dlp/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/bin/yt-dlp/yt_dlp/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: You are using an unsupported version of Python. Only Python versions 3.9 and above are supported by yt-dlp

See my answer below for a solution.

In this situation I recommend following the steps below:

Remove the current version of yt-dlp. If installed via apt, curl, pip or any other method, follow such method of install's  uninstall method.

Prepare to install python 3.9:


Update the package lists: sudo apt update
Install the necessary dependencies: sudo apt install software-properties-common
Add the PPA to your system's sources list: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa 
Update the package lists again: sudo apt update

Install python 3.9:

sudo apt install python3.9

Verify the Installation:

python3.9 --version

Install yt-dlp using python 3.9

python3.9 -m pip install yt-dlp

Note: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa - at "Third-Party Python Modules"

Note: won't work on an older version of Ubuntu not supported by deadsnakes such as Ubuntu 18.04 (OP was looking for a solution to a newer Ubuntu)
